# Google Docs page number to be 2 digits

Tags: google-docs

At the moment I cannot format the page number to be 2 digits in [Microsoft Word 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/385849/microsoft-word-2010-page-number-to-be-2-digits).

Now I need it to be also feasible in Google Docs. Please help if you know how to.

[image]

Comment: In word 2010, you can do it. Are you stuck in doing that in word 2010?

Comment: @Charan No I do need it on Google Doc - which is free to use you know ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's seems, there is no facility to modify the page numbers to 2 digit format.

Better raise a concern/issue with **[Official Google Docs Forum](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!forum/docs)**